# How to use the \n in java properly

Tags: java

Whenever I compile and run my code, the output becomes a big mess and I would like if someone could show me how to make my output look good.

```
import java.util.*;
public class JavaApplication3 {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int NumPerHamper;
        int NumHampersMade;
        int NumItemsLeftOver;
        int NumAvalable;
        double ValuePerHamper;
        double ItemCost;
        double ValueAllotedHamper;
        double ValueItemsLeftOver;
        String name="";
        Date TheDate = new Date();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of avaliable mac and cheese");
        NumAvalable = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of items per hamper");
        NumPerHamper = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Price Of Item");
        ItemCost = sc.nextDouble();

        NumHampersMade = NumAvalable / NumPerHamper;
        NumItemsLeftOver = NumAvalable % NumPerHamper;
        ValuePerHamper = NumPerHamper * ItemCost;
        ValueAllotedHamper = ValuePerHamper * NumHampersMade;
        ValueItemsLeftOver = NumItemsLeftOver * ItemCost;
        System.out.printf("\n");
        System.out.printf(TheDate + "\n");
        System.out.printf("Amount of Hampers Made: ", NumHampersMade,"\n");
        System.out.printf("The Items Left Over is: ", NumItemsLeftOver,"\n");
        System.out.printf("Each Value Of the Hampers are: $%.2f.", ValuePerHamper,"\n");
        System.out.printf("The Price Of All The Hampers Is: $%.2f.", ValueAllotedHamper,"\n");
        System.out.printf("The Value Of Mac And Cheese Is: $%.2f.", ValueItemsLeftOver,"\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `System.out.println` rather than `System.out.printf`

Comment: The only reason why I copy/pase my details is because this website said that I had just code and no details.

Comment: I can use the println but my teacher wants me to use  the "," inside the print so it will be printf and not println

Comment: and also $%.2f. doesn't work in println

Comment: In `printf` it's much better to use `%n` instead of `\n` so that it can insert `\r\n` if that is the line separator for the current system.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't right:

```
System.out.printf("Each Value Of the Hampers are: $%.2f.", ValuePerHamper,"\n");
```

The first argument (the format string) is the string you actually print, after replacing "format specifiers", or placeholders.  Format specifiers in that string, such as `%.2f`, get substituted with the other arguments.  So the second argument, `ValuePerHamper`, is used for the first specifier, `%.2f`; and the third argument, `\n`, is used for the second specifier---um, except that there aren't any other specifiers, so it doesn't get used at all.

You want to put `\n` in the format string:

```
System.out.printf("Each Value Of the Hampers are: $%.2f.\n", ValuePerHamper);
```

(`printf` also allows you to use `%n` instead of `\n`, which is more portable since it will also work on Windows systems where going to a new line needs `\r\n` instead of `\n`.)

Comment: And one more thing why is it that the out put looks like

The Items Left Over Is:

Comment: for 

System.out.printf("The Items Left Over is: \n", NumItemsLeftOver);

Comment: What is the format specifier that gets replaced with `NumItemsLeftOver`?

Comment: No.  Please have a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) (it uses `System.out.format` but that's the same as `printf`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `%n` or `\n`. Either of these should be in the first parameter in the `printf()` method like this.

```
System.out.printf("Each Value Of the Hampers are: $%.2f. %n", ValuePerHamper);
System.out.printf("The Price Of All The Hampers Is: $%.2f.%n", ValueAllotedHamper);
System.out.printf("The Value Of Mac And Cheese Is: $%.2f.%n", ValueItemsLeftOver);
```

And you are missing `%d` for the first 2 lines to display the values.

```
System.out.printf("Amount of Hampers Made: %d %n", NumHampersMade);
System.out.printf("The Items Left Over is: %d %n", NumItemsLeftOver);
```